# NoSuchMethodException when using Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I don't know what's going wrong but I'm using reflection to call a method inside of a class.

Here is what I'm doing:

ClassLoader and MAIN_PATH are already defined. I just cut it out.
The ClassLoader is a URLClassLoader and has a URL to a JAR file.
MAIN_PATH is org.example.BlahClass

```
Class mainClass = classLoader.loadClass(MAIN_PATH);
Class[] params = new Class[] { MyClass.class };
Method method = mainClass.getDeclaredMethod("onEnable", params);
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
method.invoke(null, myClass);
```

The method is declared in this class:

```
public class BlahClass implements SomeInterface {
     public void onEnable(MyClass myClass){}
     public void onDisable(){}
}
```

The full stacktrace:

```
    [17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.example.Main.commenced(org.rocket.plugin.events.PluginInitializationEvent)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at org.rocket.plugin.java.RocketPluginLoader.func_01321(RocketPluginLoader.java:42)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at org.rocket.RocketMod.setup(RocketMod.java:41)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLModContainer.handleModStateEvent(FMLModContainer.java:537)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:212)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:190)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:119)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.serverStarting(Loader.java:781)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLCommonHandler.handleServerStarting(FMLCommonHandler.java:319)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.startServer(DedicatedServer.java:289)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:500)
[17:58:11] [Server thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

View the real source here: https://gitlab.com/PizzaCrust/Rocket/blob/master/Rocket/src/org/rocket/plugin/java/RocketPluginLoader.java

Comment: Is the method you are trying to call static? What is the error?

Comment: It would help if you put the class definition and real method names and parameters here

Comment: Please show us the declaration of the method you are trying to invoke

Comment: What is a value of `MAIN_PATH`?

Comment: Added it to the post.

Comment: The class is really called `Class`? Don't do that.

Comment: @EJP no, its just a random class name. it's not the actual one.

Comment: In other words this isn't the real code. So posting it was a complete waste of time.

Comment: @EJP Anyways, if you still want to solve it go to the source of the file. It contains the code that I am using.

Comment: You are attempting to call a none-static method without an instance.

Comment: @mlk this gives `NullPointerException`, not `NoSuchMethodException`

Comment: And thus why a comment and not an answer.

Comment: **What is the full stack trace** and the results of `System.out.println(mainClass)` and `for(Method m : mainClass.getMethods()) System.out.println(m)`? I.e.  is the class  you have what you think you have?

Comment: In the code linked you call `method.invoke(mainClass, new org.rocket.plugin.events.PluginInitializationEvent());`. This would end up with a `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Can we get a look at the code for `org.example.Main`?

Comment: @mlk the results of it is: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=eU6cZNhY

Comment: @mlk heres the code: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=5AkdRV7C

Comment: @CatSources You are loading a class from another jar file, right? What of these classes are defined in your application, and what are defined in another jar?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak here are the classes defined in my application: https://gitlab.com/PizzaCrust/Rocket/tree/master and the here is the other:  http://postimg.org/image/f0lsfiow3/cc18bbbd/

Comment: @CatSources So you expect external jar file to know about class `org.rocket.plugin.events.PluginInitializationEvent` defined in your jar file? How does the other jar file compiles?

Comment: Fine. I added the JAR file to the other JAR file's build path in Eclipse and expect it to use the classes inside of my JAR file.

Comment: @CatSources I think there is some design problem here. Your application (say `1.jar`) takes `2.jar` as a parameter. However, `2.jar` needs to have a dependency on `1.jar` in order to compile. This sounds to me like circular dependency. I am sorry, but I don't think I can help you with your problem.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak The 2.jar is not complete. It only contains the methods that I want to share. The application loads the JAR file with the dependencies that the 1.jar is needed.

Comment: Here is what I think happens: JAR has 2.jar containing methods the APP contains. APP loads JAR and JAR can access methods in APP.

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchMethodException` can be thrown only by `mainClass.getDeclaredMethod("onEnable", params)`. It means that class `mainClass` does not have method called `onEnable` which takes a single parameter of type `MyClass`.

The only line which can cause this problem is `classLoader.loadClass(MAIN_PATH)` and my bet is that you are not loading the class you think you are loading, i.e. you define `MAIN_PATH = "org.example.BlahClass"` but your class `BlahClass` is not in package `org.example`. Another reason could be related to `classLoader` - you have not shown how you initialise it either.

Try adding a following check:

```
if (mainClass == org.example.BlahClass.class) {
    System.out.println("It's ok!");
} else {
    System.out.println("It's not ok!");
}
```

Another reason may be related to `params`. `getDeclaredMethod` has a second parameter being a var-arg - `Class<?>... parameterTypes`. You pass a single parameter of type `Class[]` so it should be fine, because var-arg is just an array. However, depending on JDK, it may expect the first parameter to actually be an array, and you are trying to get a method with the following signature: `onEnable(java.lang.Class[])` instead (which doesn't exist). Try doing this instead:

```
mainClass.getDeclaredMethod("onEnable", MyClass.class)
```

Comment: The class is in a another file. (URLClassLoader)

Comment: If I remove the parameter all together, including the interface of the class and the class altogether, it works.

Comment: @CatSources Sorry, I am confused. How can it work if you delete a class, where the method is declared?

Comment: Sorry, just worded it incorrectly. Not deleting the class, remove the **parameter** in the class and interface. Including not invoking it with a parameter.

Comment: @CatSources have you tried doing this `mainClass.getDeclaredMethod("onEnable", MyClass.class)`?

Comment: @CatSources What about using `getMethod` instead of `getDeclaredMethod`? I have checked it already and there should be no difference in this case, but if nothing else helped, I am out of ideas.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. Perhaps you want to see the full source. Here it is: https://gitlab.com/PizzaCrust/Rocket/blob/master/Rocket/src/org/rocket/plugin/java/RocketPluginLoader.java

Comment: @CatSources I think the problem may be `URLClassLoader`. I have never used it before and I am not sure how it works. You should probably add it to your question.

Comment: I have added it to the question now.